# Spark :org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Executor is not registered

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, emr

I am running spark 1.4.1 on EMR. I am trying to process huge data on EMR using 10 NODES with memory 122G and 16core each. i am getting below exceptions after sometime.

```
 org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Executor is not registered (appId=application_1439264479594_0002, execId=17)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.getBlockData(ExternalShuffleBlockResolver.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.receive(ExternalShuffleBlockHandler.java:74)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processRpcRequest(TransportRequestHandler.java:114)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:87)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:101)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:254)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:333)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:319)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:787)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:130)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Could somebody tell me how should i debug this.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try increasing spark.mesos.executor.memoryOverhead

Comment: this should be a comment. Not an answer to the question. Once you earn 50 rep, you will be privileged to post comment every where. As of now, it is not an answer.